# why [!charlist1] and [characters not in charlist1] not working in same way

Tags: sql, wildcard

So here are the 2 queries I wrote

```
select Name from tblEmployees where Name not like '%[! -.]%[ .-]%[! -.]%' order by Name;

select Name from tblEmployees where Name not like '%[a-z]%[ .-]%[a-z]%' order by Name;
```

surprisingly both are having different results and even more surprising is the fact that 1st query shows more results than 2nd one..

any possible reasons why both queries not working in same way,

I don't think because the characters used in `tblEmployees` in Names have any other characters than `a-z`', `''` (space) `.` and `-`.

I have run the queries in SOL server management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
[^ -.]
```

instead of

```
[! -.]
```

Comment: It should also be noted that `space-.` will match all characters between `space` and `.`, in the same way that `a-z` matches all alphabetical characters. (Using space rather than a literal because it won't format right in comments)

Comment: hmm, that space-. thing is a blunder I missed, and using ^ worked, Thanks

Comment: Can you tell why ! dosent work but ^ does, in w3schools both are syntax given.

Comment: I haven't ever seen ! used that way, and I don't think any of biggest database systems allows that.